# Dark or Night Mode will not stay persistantly dark with localStorage or Cookies

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, local-storage

i'm trying to set Night (or Dark!) Mode persistently throughout the site i am working on using minimal code.

I have tried setting a Cookie and localStorage with no effect. Here is the code i am working with.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-2 night-mode-button"><i class="fas fa-moon" ></i></button>
```

using this JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var button = $('.night-mode-button');
  var container = $('.content-box');
    button.click(function() {
        container.toggleClass('-nightmode');
        localStorage.setItem('.content-box','-nightmode');
        document.documentElement.classList.toggle('-nightmode');
        console.log("night mode enabled, but not here to stay!");
    });

// Swaps sun/moon icon
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-moon");
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-sun");
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question, what exactly means "_will not stay persistantly_"?

Comment: You only set the local storage - you never get it anywhere so how do you expect it to persist?  Also, when you toggle off the class - you don't remove it from local storage either

Comment: I'd like (let's say) a cookie to be set once the user clicks the button to set Night Mode and the site will stay night mode throughout the session. Thanks for looking!

Comment: The solution that i gave you yesterday on your other post... didn't it work?

Comment: Hello @Devashish i haven't found a solution yet. This is my first and only post here. What was your solution you mentioned? Thank you for looking.